# How to handle template specialization with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I have the following code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

static inline void print (void)
{
  ;
}

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
static inline void print (Head h, Tail... t)
{
  std::cout << h << std::endl;
  print(t...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  print("string", 42, 3.43, true, 'c');

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to specialize for the first type, Head, with, for example, a bool? What I am looking is the proper syntax I would need to do this. I have tried adding this extra template,

```
template <bool, typename... Tail>
static inline void print (bool h, Tail... t)
{
  std::cout << "I'm a bool!" << std::endl;
  print(t...);
}
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ there is no such thing as a partial specialization of a function template.

That is true for C++03 and also for C++11, and is true for all function templates not only variadic ones.

You can overload the function though:

```
template <typename... Tail>
static inline void print (bool h, Tail... t)
{
  std::cout << "I'm a bool!" << std::endl;
  print(t...);
}
```

That overload will be used when the first argument is a `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

Function overload is enough, but you need to declare all the signature first, the code below works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/859635a5f4ef3635), but if you remove the declaration of the bool overload like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25fc1931372ba356), then it will not be picked.

```
#include <iostream>

void print (void){}
template <typename... Tail>
void print (bool b, Tail&&... t);
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void print (Head&& h, Tail&&... t);


template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void print (Head&& h, Tail&&... t) {
  std::cout << std::forward<Heal>(h) << " ";
  print(std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
}

template <typename... Tail>
void print (bool , Tail&&... t) {
  std::cout <<"bool" << " ";
  print(std::forward<Tail>(t)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  print("string", 42, true, 3.43, true, 'c');
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT : Added universal reference for a real solution.